# Как оформить прямую речь?

Tags: пунктуация

В тексте попалось вот такое предложение (точнее, два предложения): *"Когда человека нашли помощники, то решили, что ногу поклевала эта ворона. Попытались закидать камнями, с криками «Кыш, мерзавка!»"*
После слова "криками" стояло тире, но меня исправили, что тут вообще никакого знака препинания не нужно. Хотя я бы, скорее, заменил тире на двоеточие. Интересно, почему тут не нужен никакой знак препинания и правильно ли это?

Answer (score 2):

Правильно: Попытались закидать камнями, с криками "Кыш, мерзавка!"

Запятая используется для обособления обстоятельства, обозначая присоединительный характер сообщения.

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

Нераспространенная   прямая речь может являться членом предложения – подлежащим, дополнением, несогласованным определением. В этом случае прямая речь не имеет собственной интонации и вписывается интонационную модель всего предложения.  Прямая речь заключается в кавычки, но двоеточие перед ней не ставится.

ПРИМЕР: На вопрос «Чьи это луга?» ему никто не мог толком ответить.

Comment: Добавлю только (это важно), что в конце предложения (раз прямая речь без двоеточия, то есть член предложения)должна стоять точка: Попытались закидать камнями, с криками "Кыш, мерзавка!".

Comment: Да, точка нужна, выражение в кавычках входит в состав повествовательного предложения и собственной интонации не имеет.